# VirtualBox и машина на внешнем диске

Tags: windows, virtualbox

Возникла такая проблема:

Имеется установленный на машине VirtualBox и виртуальная машина на внешнем HDD. К виртуальной машине подключен .vdi диск типа "множественное подключение", т.е. сама машина при запуске пишет всё в отдельный {guid}.vdi.

Проблема в том, что каждый раз после перезагрузки компьютера VirtualBox не видит этот самый {guid}.vdi (или говорит что не видит его, а на самом деле не видит его родительский диск) и не может стартовать виртуальную машину. Переносной диск при этом, естественно, подключён.

Исправляется это (до следующей перезагрузки) созданием новой виртуальной машины с опцией "у меня уже есть готовый диск" и выбором обоих этих дисков по-очереди, с последующим прерыванием процесса.

В связи с этим вопрос: куда в настройки VirtualBox (или в его xml конфиг) можно прописать пути и GUID'ы этих двух дисков, чтобы он раз и навсегда запомнил где они находятся и не терзал мне мозг?..

В файле `%USERPROFILE%\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml` есть строчка
`<ExtraDataItem name="GUI/RecentListHD" value="..." />`

где сохранены правильные пути к обоим файлам, но ему на это плевать.

Доп. информация:

- "разностный" диск лежит в папке виртуальной машины, рядом с .vbox файлом;
- "родительский" диск лежит в отдельной папке на том же диске;
- внешний диск всегда монтируется на одну и ту же букву.